Need to Reinstall GRUB | Repair Boot after MB failed. OS on Raid1 / LVM partitions
My UEFI motherboard failed.  I am running 22.04LTS on a bootable Raid1 array on a LVM layer.
It is not a dual boot setup.
Of course UEFI requires a small partition in fat32 to act as the boot, efi when the OS is on the RAID partition.
I got a replacement MB then found a Drew Howden Tech video on youtube:
How to Reinstall GRUB | Repair Boot on Linux
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhxBJ3yh2OY
which helped a lot, but did not address RAID and LVM.  I got those mounted and activated and did get GRUB re-installed on the RAID partition from the live session, but…
When I reboot into the GRUB> console and try to load the kernel using:
grub> set root=[partition] (example: set root=(hd3,gpt3))
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3)
grub>  initrd /boot/initrd.img
grub> boot  

I get error messages.
If I point to (hd3,gpt3) my RAID/ LVM root partition I get -
error: unknown filesystem
or
error: partition hd3,gpt3: no known filesystem detected
If I point to the (hd3,gpt1) boot,efi partition I get
error: file ‘/root/vmlinuz’ not found
My system is setup like so:

Blockquotexubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0               7:0    0   2.5G  1 loop  /rofs
loop1               7:1    0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
loop2               7:2    0  63.3M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1822
loop3               7:3    0  91.7M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop4               7:4    0  49.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/18357
loop5               7:5    0 346.3M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop6               7:6    0 240.6M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/2356
sda                 8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1              8:1    0     1G  0 part
├─sda2              8:2    0   200M  0 part
└─sda3              8:3    0 878.9G  0 part
└─md0             9:0    0 878.8G  0 raid1
├─vg0-lv--0   253:0    0    12G  0 lvm
├─vg0-lv--HOM 253:1    0   124G  0 lvm
├─vg0-lv--USR 253:2    0    50G  0 lvm
├─vg0-lv--VAR 253:3    0    25G  0 lvm
├─vg0-lv--SWP 253:4    0    10G  0 lvm
└─vg0-lv--OPT 253:5    0    10G  0 lvm
sdb                 8:16   1  28.9G  0 disk
├─sdb1              8:17   1  18.6G  0 part  /media/xubuntu/usbdata
├─sdb2              8:18   1     1M  0 part
├─sdb3              8:19   1   244M  0 part
├─sdb4              8:20   1   2.9G  0 part  /cdrom
└─sdb5              8:21   1   7.2G  0 part

sda                 8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk        < hd3
├─sda1              8:1    0     1G  0 part    < Boot,EFI

├─vg0-lv--0   253:0    0    12G  0 lvm     <--boot and root on here
   
sdb                 8:16   1  28.9G  0 disk    < USB Live stick  hd0
├─sdb1              8:17   1  18.6G  0 part  /media/xubuntu/usbdata

In the live session, thunar shows the path to the boot DIR as:
/media/xubuntu/40ef0240-38ff-4cef-b122-870b3c5a13fa/boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-101-generic  

/media/xubuntu/40ef0240-38ff-4cef-b122-870b3c5a13fa/boot/initrd.img

Do I need to specify:
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dm-0/vg0-lv—0
OR to the boot,efi DIR -
grub> set boot=(hd3,gpt1)
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz boot=/dev/sda1
can I copy  vmlinuz and initrd.img to the ‘usbdata’ NTFS partition on my live stick and point grub to the files there?
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sdb1
would I also set the root to the usb drive
grub> set root=(hd0,gpt1)
I don’t know if GRUB has limitations reading files on the md0 / vg0 partition or what?
Do I point GRUB to the boot,efi partition as boot, not root?   set boot=(hd3,gpt1)
The ubuntu boot repair utility could not navigate this either.
Thanks for any help you can offer.

Did you install the lvm2 drivers? I think grub then has to be installed with the lvm mounted so it adds its driver for LVM. Not sure if similar for RAID or not. Rerun Boot-Repair after mounting LVM. And post link to Summary report that it creates. Perhaps more info:  chroot with UEFI, LVM, encryption on NVMe drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349833&p=13602088#post13602088
UEFI needs to mount ESP directly, not in LVM. Most with RAID that I have seen have a separate boot drive, often small SSD and RAID on data drives. Note that RAID is not backup but for uptime.

Yes, LVM2 was already installed.      https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/24xmNrk9BN/  The ESP is the first one on my system drive.  Oversize at 1GB. I'll read thru the Ubuntuforum thread for the chroot info.  Thanks, oldfred.

Line 271 shows the grub in the ESP, but that UUID is not seen anywhere else in report? It should be either / (root) or /boot if separate partition where grub.cfg is. Is that sda2 shown as unknown which may need fsck, if really ext4. I see LVM, but no RAID as only 2 TB sda drive. And sdb is 32GB live installer. See line 309. MDADM has replaced dmraid.

I think the ESP uuid -A5C7 was generated for my new MB.  A few steps later in this process, I need to get into nano and edit my Fstab file to update it.  That comes after I get the OS booted up, so I can "sudo update-grub".  /root and /boot are in sda3, the raid - LVM partion.  sda2 was created in error when I set up my 1st UEFI system a couple years ago.  It is only 200mb.  I'm running RAID degraded, I pulled the 2nd drive so I'd have a 2nd chance at re-configuring the system, if I really botch it up.  Oh, I run mdadm, I should remove the dmraid packages then...
